# Добавить пульсацию на чекбокс

Tags: javascript, html, css

Пытался добавить `box-shadow` для checkbox`a

```
.warning-pulse {
animation: checkbox-pulse 1.2s infinite;
}

@keyframes checkbox-pulse {
0% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
70% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
}
100% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

}

Вот код чекбокса

```
<input type="checkbox" class="warning-pulse">
```

Проблема в том, что при добавлении анимации с `box-shadow` тень не учитывает закруглённость чекбокса
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] - это как выглядит тень.

Вопрос, как можно создать чекбокс чтобы у него была нормальная анимация с `box-shadow`? Если необходимо создавать свой чекбокс, то можно ли как-то без JS сделать, чтобы при `checked` кастомного чекбокса был `checked` основного? Это по сути обязательно, ведь иначе код сайта поломается. Если не получится с `box-shadow`, то может быть можно сделать с `background-color` ?

Заранее спасибо

Comment: _«тень начинается не с конца чекбокса, а на 1-2 пиксель дальше»_ - нипанятна. На скриншоте вроде нет такого... вижу только как уголки от бордер-радиуса торчатъ.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Вернее будет что уголки у box-shadow неверно строятся

Comment: _«Если необходимо создавать свой чекбокс, то можно ли как-то без JS сделать, чтобы при checked кастомного чекбокса был checked основного?»_ - конечно можно:  `[type="checkbox"] { display: none; }` плюс `[type="checkbox"] + label::before { <псевдоэлементом имитируем вид пустого чекбокса> }` плюс `[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before { <меняем вид добавив галочку> }` Обычно это так делается. _//Про помещение в лейбл - это я зря: такое можно с вложенным в лейбл элементом попробовать (`label > [type="checkbox"] + span`), но имхо это менее удобно будет (fixed)._

Comment: @yar85 жаль, что это не border-radius, а системный вид чекбокса на macOS, т.е. через css отдельно не корректируется.

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov, так я и не писал что этот бордер-радиус (а это именно он) через CSS корректируется... то что инпуты стилизуются очень ограниченно - общеизвестный факт. Но связан он не исключительно с макосью, а с тем что элементы форм рендерятся на базе системных (в любой ОС). Это собираются менять, но как бывает в вебе, процесс может затянуться на годы... хотя, не так давно Хром выкатил обновление (91 релиз) где некоторые элементы ввода на ведроиде рендерятся **не** на базе системных. Возможно, это первый шаг, а возможно всего лишь случай, который останется исключением... время покажет :)

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov, сколько ждали нормального вертикального центрирования пока флексбоксы не стандартизировали - 10, 15 лет? Хорошо если мы хотя бы на своем веку застанем кроссплатформенные инпуты с полной стилизацией))) Там ведь мало реализовать, надо еще унять вопли драматизма тех кто с пеной у рта противостоит подобным новшествам: кто из консерватизма (W3C), кто из страха - взять хотя бы тот балаган который был вокруг свежего в данный момент Filesystem API. "Уязвимости, уязвимости, мы все умрем". Такое впечатление что люди уже забыли сервлеты и Flash, а точнее огромное количество дыр в них))

Answer (score 1):

1. Можно анимировать не сам чекбокс, а *соседний* элемент, который визуально может быть расположен под чекбоксом. Тогда уголки закрасятся.

```css
.checkbox {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
}

.warning-pulse {
  margin: 0;
}

.warning-pulse + .pulse {
  animation: checkbox-pulse 1.2s infinite;
  width: calc(100% - 2px);
  height: calc(100% - 2px);
  position: absolute;
  left: 1px;
  top: 1px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.pulse.rounded {
  border-radius:50%;
}


@keyframes checkbox-pulse {
  0% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
  }
  70% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="warning-pulse">
  <div class="pulse"></div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="warning-pulse">
  <div class="pulse rounded"></div>
</div>
```

2. Можно полностью сбросить все стили отображения (и видимость) чекбокса при помощи свойства [`appearance:none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/appearance), заменив их собственными. Это не повлияет на логику работы чекбокса и смену состояния checked.